# AWS CLI - How to query snapshots created after a specific date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to query the snapshots created after a specific date and it is returning no results. The query I am trying is below:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime >= `2017-06-01`].{id:SnapshotId}' --owner-ids nnnnnnnnnnn
```

If I remove the --query section, all snapshots are returned, so I know it's something to do with the query.

I tried checking the [JMESPath docs](http://jmespath.org) but there isn't much there on date manipulation. I also tried replicating the syntax in the example [here](https://serverfault.com/a/708096/375417) to no avail.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code example is working perfectly well for me! (With my Account ID.)

Find the date on a snapshot, then put that date in the query -- one day before and then run it again for one day after. That should help you track down the strange behaviour.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime >= `2016-08-30`].{id:SnapshotId}' --owner-ids 123456789012
[
    {
        "id": "snap-e044d613"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "snap-f4444506"
    }
]

$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime >= `2016-08-31`].{id:SnapshotId}' --owner-ids 123456789012
[]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still no dice changing the dates though. I may see if AWS Support can help.

Comment: Perhaps check that you're up-do-date? `sudo pip install awscli --upgrade`

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein! It needed an upgrade! That old chestnut!

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of AWS CLI  and jquery so I have found the easiest way to list all the snapshots created before a specific timestamp:-

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --output json | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime > "2019-12-18")'
```